# Defining function for arithmetic expressions

Tags: semantics, denotational-semantics

I've got these arithmetic expressions

```
a  ::=  n  |  x  |  a1 + a2  |  a1 ? a2  |  a1 − a2
```

which are a part of language.

An undefined element is allowed ⊥ which extends the set of intergers to Z∪{⊥}.

**Problem:**

I need to define the function

> A: Aexp → (State → Z∪{⊥})

by defining equations for each form of the arithmetic expression `a`.

Now I've tried to come up with an solution but I am pretty sure I am wrong and I gotta admit I am pretty stuck.

Some help understanding this problem would be great.

Comment: What is it you tried, and where/how specifically did you get stuck?

Comment: I should gain some confidence in yourself, starting with the use of a capital "I" when writing in the first person, and more generally by abiding by the rules of English syntax. - - - Then it is hard to answer you, if you do not specify at least informally what this syntax is supposed to mean. I suppose `n` is the representation of a number in Z. But what is "`a1 ? a2`" ?

Comment: Do you know how `State` is defined ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Here is one example

$A($ `a1 - a2`$, s) = minus(A($ `a1`$,s),A($ `a2`$,s))$

or alternatively

$A($ `a1 - a2`$) = \lambda s . minus(A($ `a1`$,s),A($ `a2`$,s))$

where $minus$ is the substraction in $\mathbb Z\cup\{\bot\}$